# why this function is not working in Kotlin

Tags: java, function, kotlin

I'm trying to make a function that removes all spaces in the given string. This is my code:

```
fun nonSpaceString(s: String): String {
  var result = " "
  for (index in 0..s.length-1) {
    if (s[index] != ' ') {
      result += s[index]
    }
  }
  return result
}
fun main(){
nonSpaceString("abc d e")
}
```

But the result is holding "a" and then holding "ab" but the end result holds nothing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have initialized the result with a space character. So the result starts with a space that may confuse you. Apart from that, your function is working fine.
Additionally, you can use the replace function to remove all spaces from a string

```
"abc d e".replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "")
```